# Inserting variable into array item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of elements from my webpage which I am trying to then insert some html, stored as a variable into a matching array item. For example

```
<div class="play">
  <div>
    <p>Item to be inserted after this p tag</p>
  </div>
</div>

var elements = $('.play');
//elements length = 4;
var item = '<p>HTML to be inserted</p>'
$(item).appendTo(elements[1]);
```

In the above code I am trying to insert 'item' into the second value in the array within the child div shown in the html, however I am unsure how to insert it into the child div. At present this inserts 'item' after the parent html tag containing .play.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about selecting the child div, not the `.play` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `elements` isn't an array, it's a jQuery object, which means you can use jQuery methods to traverse through the DOM:

```
elements.eq(1).find("div").append(item);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgQ7g/

`.eq(1)` selects the second item but returns it wrapped in another jQuery object, so then you can use `.find("div")` to get to the child div and `.append()` your `item` to it.

Comment: This is the option I have gone for, works the best and doesn't affect other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('.play').find('p').after(item);
```

This inserts content AFTER a selected element in the DOM. It also does it for all the classes named `.play`

If you need to specify an index, I recommend a function:

```
function appendPlay(index, content) {
    $('.play').eq(index).find('p').after(content);        
}

appendPlay(2, '<p>HTML to be inserted</p>');
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/S9SZC/3/)

Comment: *Why* do you recommend an extra function and not just `$('.play').eq(1).find('p').after('<p>HTML to be inserted</p>');`?

Comment: @Bergi: "If you need to specify an index, I recommend a function:"

Comment: Yes, I read that. But I do recommend not to use a function. So do you have any reasoning?

Comment: Because `1` may not be the only index the OP wants to append? What if they want to append index `2` or later on, `3`. You've tripled your code. Or what if the content changes?

Comment: I would create a function only if I *know* that it is reused, which does not seem to be the case here… But OK.

Answer (score -1):

please try using

```
var element = $('.play div p');
var item = '<p>HTML to be inserted</p>'
$(element).parent().append(item);
```

Edited
from

```
var element = $('.play div');
var item = '<p>HTML to be inserted</p>'
$(element).append(item);
```

Comment: But that would add the item to _all_ such divs, not just the second one.

Comment: Regarding your edit, my previous comment still applies. The OP has four `.play` divs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use link below. (I edited code after comment)

You should write code like;

```
var selector = ".play",
    text = "<p>HTML to be inserted</p>";
$(selector + " div p").eq(1).after(text);
```

http://jsbin.com/esesul/5/

Comment: The question indicates that there are _four_ `'.play'` elements, and that the item should be added to the second. Your code adds to them all...

Comment: What if the first `.play` does not contain one `div p`, but zero or two or more?

Comment: Yes. You can change eq(1) to another one to get other elemeents.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess this would work:

```
$(item).appendTo($(elements));
```

But a better solution would be using:

```
$('.play').find('p').after(item);
```

Comment: No, since he only wants to insert into the second `elements`, not in all of them